# How to create Select List for Country and States/province in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am new to MVC and even asp..

I want to create a form in MVC. With the help of some examples I am able to create TextBoxes, but I now I don't understand how to create Select List./

I tried searching many examples for implementing Select List in MVC, but I am not able to understand.

I have a Form which is half coded in HTML and half in MVC.

Here is my Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MedAvail.Applications.MedProvision.Web.Models
{
    public class AddressViewModel
    {
        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}




<form id="locationInfo">
    <h1>Location Information</h1>
    <table width="80%" id="locInfo">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="20%" />
            <col />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.Label("Country")</th>
            <td>
                <select required="">
                    <option>Select Country</option>
                    <option>Canada</option>
                    <option>United States</option>
                </select>
                <span class="required">*</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.State)</th>
            <td>
                <select required="">
                    <option>Select State</option>
                    <option>State 1</option>
                    <option>State 2</option>
                    <option>State 3</option>
                        ...............
                </select><span class="required">*</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.PostalCode)</th>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.PostalCode)<span class="required">*</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.City)</th>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.City)<span class="required">*</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.StreetAddress1)</th>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.StreetAddress1)<span class="required">*</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.StreetAddress2)</th>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.StreetAddress2)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.PhoneNumber)</th>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.PhoneNumber)</td>
        </tr>

    </table>


    <div role="button" class="marginTop50 marginBottom">
        <input type="button" id="step3Back" value="Back" class="active" />
        <input type="button" id="step3confirmNext" value="Next" class="active marginLeft50" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Please guide me on how to create the Select List for this kind of form.

Comment: What is the problem? Your HTML and MVC view code looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for looking, My HTML code still contains Select list in HTML...
But I want to convert these Select List for Country n City into MVC like done for Text Boxes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thank You All! I am able to to load Select List as per MVC now My Working Code is below:

HTML+MVC Code in View:-

```
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.Label("Country")</th>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x =>x.Province,SelectListItemHelper.GetCountryList())<span class="required">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Province)</th>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x =>x.Province,SelectListItemHelper.GetProvincesList())<span class="required">*</span></td>
    </tr>
```

Created a Controller under "UTIL" folder:
Code:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MedAvail.Applications.MedProvision.Web.Util
{
    public class SelectListItemHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetProvincesList()
        {
            IList<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem{Text = "California", Value = "B"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Alaska", Value = "B"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Illinois", Value = "B"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Texas", Value = "B"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Washington", Value = "B"}

            };
            return items;
        }


        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCountryList()
        {
            IList<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem{Text = "United States", Value = "B"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Canada", Value = "B"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "United Kingdom", Value = "B"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Texas", Value = "B"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Washington", Value = "B"}

            };
            return items;
        }


    }
}
```

And its working COOL now :-)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 73):

```
public static List<SelectListItem> States = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() {Text="Alabama", Value="AL"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Alaska", Value="AK"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Arizona", Value="AZ"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Arkansas", Value="AR"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="California", Value="CA"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Colorado", Value="CO"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Connecticut", Value="CT"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="District of Columbia", Value="DC"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Delaware", Value="DE"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Florida", Value="FL"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Georgia", Value="GA"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Hawaii", Value="HI"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Idaho", Value="ID"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Illinois", Value="IL"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Indiana", Value="IN"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Iowa", Value="IA"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Kansas", Value="KS"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Kentucky", Value="KY"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Louisiana", Value="LA"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Maine", Value="ME"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Maryland", Value="MD"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Massachusetts", Value="MA"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Michigan", Value="MI"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Minnesota", Value="MN"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Mississippi", Value="MS"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Missouri", Value="MO"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Montana", Value="MT"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Nebraska", Value="NE"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Nevada", Value="NV"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="New Hampshire", Value="NH"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="New Jersey", Value="NJ"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="New Mexico", Value="NM"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="New York", Value="NY"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="North Carolina", Value="NC"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="North Dakota", Value="ND"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Ohio", Value="OH"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Oklahoma", Value="OK"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Oregon", Value="OR"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Pennsylvania", Value="PA"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Rhode Island", Value="RI"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="South Carolina", Value="SC"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="South Dakota", Value="SD"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Tennessee", Value="TN"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Texas", Value="TX"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Utah", Value="UT"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Vermont", Value="VT"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Virginia", Value="VA"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Washington", Value="WA"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="West Virginia", Value="WV"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Wisconsin", Value="WI"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Wyoming", Value="WY"}
    };
```

How we do it is put this method into a class and then call the class from the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.State, Class.States)
```

Comment: This results in undesired behavior if you visit a model page with this attribute set, and then visit another model page with the attribute blank. In the second page, it will be set to whatever the last selected value was.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for this

Here's what I did:

1.Created an Extensions.cs file in a Utils folder.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Web.ProjectName.Utils
{
    public class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStatesList()
        {
            IList<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem() {Text="Alabama", Value="AL"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Alaska", Value="AK"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Arizona", Value="AZ"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Arkansas", Value="AR"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="California", Value="CA"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Colorado", Value="CO"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Connecticut", Value="CT"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="District of Columbia", Value="DC"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Delaware", Value="DE"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Florida", Value="FL"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Georgia", Value="GA"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Hawaii", Value="HI"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Idaho", Value="ID"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Illinois", Value="IL"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Indiana", Value="IN"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Iowa", Value="IA"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Kansas", Value="KS"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Kentucky", Value="KY"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Louisiana", Value="LA"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Maine", Value="ME"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Maryland", Value="MD"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Massachusetts", Value="MA"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Michigan", Value="MI"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Minnesota", Value="MN"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Mississippi", Value="MS"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Missouri", Value="MO"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Montana", Value="MT"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Nebraska", Value="NE"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Nevada", Value="NV"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="New Hampshire", Value="NH"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="New Jersey", Value="NJ"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="New Mexico", Value="NM"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="New York", Value="NY"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="North Carolina", Value="NC"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="North Dakota", Value="ND"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Ohio", Value="OH"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Oklahoma", Value="OK"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Oregon", Value="OR"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Pennsylvania", Value="PA"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Rhode Island", Value="RI"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="South Carolina", Value="SC"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="South Dakota", Value="SD"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Tennessee", Value="TN"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Texas", Value="TX"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Utah", Value="UT"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Vermont", Value="VT"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Virginia", Value="VA"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Washington", Value="WA"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="West Virginia", Value="WV"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Wisconsin", Value="WI"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text="Wyoming", Value="WY"}
            };
            return states;
        }
    }
}
```

2.In my model, where state will be abbreviated (e.g. "AL", "NY", etc.):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Web.ProjectName.Models
{
    public class ContactForm
    {

        ...

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        [RegularExpression("[A-Z]{2}")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        ...

    }
}
```

2.In my view I referenced it:

```
  @model Web.ProjectName.Models.ContactForm

  ...

  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.State, new { @class = "form-label" })
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.State, Web.ProjectName.Utils.Extensions.GetStatesList(), new { @class = "form-control" })

  ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Designing You Model:

```
Public class ModelName
{
    ...// Properties
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListName { get; set; }
}
```

Prepare and bind List to Model in Controller :

```
    public ActionResult Index(ModelName model)
    {
        var items = // Your List of data
        model.ListName = items.Select(x=> new SelectListItem() {
                    Text = x.prop,
                    Value = x.prop2
               });
    }
```

In You View :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.prop2,Model.ListName)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am able to to load Select List as per MVC now My Working Code is below:

Comment: Does this require:

```using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;```
```using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;```

Answer (score 3):

So many ways to do this... for #NetCore use Lib..

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq; // only required when .AsEnumerable() is used
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
```

Model...

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
  public class MyModel
  {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string StatePick { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    [StringLength(35, ErrorMessage = "State cannot be longer than 35 characters.")]
    public SelectList StateList { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Controller...

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// create SelectListItem from strings
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isValue">defaultValue is SelectListItem.Value is true, SelectListItem.Text if false</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private SelectListItem newItem(string value, string text, string defaultValue = "", bool isValue = false)
    {
        SelectListItem ss = new SelectListItem();
        ss.Text = text;
        ss.Value = value;

        // select default by Value or Text
        if (isValue && ss.Value == defaultValue || !isValue && ss.Text == defaultValue)
        {
            ss.Selected = true;
        }

        return ss;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// this pulls the state name from _context and sets it as the default for the selectList
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="myState">sets default value for list of states</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private SelectList getStateList(string myState = "")
    {
        List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem chosen = new SelectListItem();

        // set default selected state to OHIO
        string defaultValue = "OH";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myState))
        {
            defaultValue = myState;
        }

        try
        {
            states.Add(newItem("AL", "Alabama", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("AK", "Alaska", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("AZ", "Arizona", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("AR", "Arkansas", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("CA", "California", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("CO", "Colorado", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("CT", "Connecticut", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("DE", "Delaware", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("DC", "District of Columbia", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("FL", "Florida", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("GA", "Georgia", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("HI", "Hawaii", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("ID", "Idaho", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("IL", "Illinois", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("IN", "Indiana", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("IA", "Iowa", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("KS", "Kansas", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("KY", "Kentucky", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("LA", "Louisiana", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("ME", "Maine", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("MD", "Maryland", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("MA", "Massachusetts", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("MI", "Michigan", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("MN", "Minnesota", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("MS", "Mississippi", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("MO", "Missouri", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("MT", "Montana", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("NE", "Nebraska", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("NV", "Nevada", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("NH", "New Hampshire", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("NJ", "New Jersey", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("NM", "New Mexico", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("NY", "New York", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("NC", "North Carolina", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("ND", "North Dakota", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("OH", "Ohio", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("OK", "Oklahoma", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("OR", "Oregon", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("PA", "Pennsylvania", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("RI", "Rhode Island", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("SC", "South Carolina", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("SD", "South Dakota", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("TN", "Tennessee", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("TX", "Texas", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("UT", "Utah", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("VT", "Vermont", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("VA", "Virginia", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("WA", "Washington", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("WV", "West Virginia", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("WI", "Wisconsin", defaultValue, true));
            states.Add(newItem("WY", "Wyoming", defaultValue, true));

            foreach (SelectListItem state in states)
            {
                if (state.Selected)
                {
                    chosen = state;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            string ss = "ERR!   " + err.Source + "   " + err.GetType().ToString() + "\r\n" + err.Message.Replace("\r\n", "   ");
            ss = this.sendError("Online getStateList Request", ss, _errPassword);
            // return error
        }

        // .AsEnumerable() is not required in the pass.. it is an extension of Linq
        SelectList myList = new SelectList(states.AsEnumerable(), "Value", "Text", chosen);

        object val = myList.SelectedValue;

        return myList;
    }

    public ActionResult pickState(MyModel pData)
    {
        if (pData.StateList == null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pData.StatePick)) // state abbrev, value collected onchange
            {
                pData.StateList = getStateList();
            }
            else
            {
                pData.StateList = getStateList(pData.StatePick);
            }

            // assign values to state list items
            try
            {
                SelectListItem si = (SelectListItem)pData.StateList.SelectedValue;
                pData.state = si.Value;
                pData.StatePick = si.Value;
            }
            catch { }
        } 
    return View(pData);
    }
}
```

pickState.cshtml...

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "United States of America";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title - Where are you...</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.state)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">            
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatePick, Model.StateList, new { OnChange = "state.value = this.value;" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.state)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateList)
    </div>         
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I too liked Jordan's answer and implemented it myself.  I only needed to abbreviations so in case someone else needs the same:

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStatesList()
    {
        IList<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem() {Text="AL", Value="AL"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="AK", Value="AK"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="AZ", Value="AZ"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="AR", Value="AR"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="CA", Value="CA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="CO", Value="CO"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="CT", Value="CT"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="DC", Value="DC"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="DE", Value="DE"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="FL", Value="FL"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="GA", Value="GA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="HI", Value="HI"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="ID", Value="ID"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="IL", Value="IL"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="IN", Value="IN"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="IA", Value="IA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="KS", Value="KS"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="KY", Value="KY"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="LA", Value="LA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="ME", Value="ME"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="MD", Value="MD"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="MA", Value="MA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="MI", Value="MI"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="MN", Value="MN"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="MS", Value="MS"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="MO", Value="MO"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="MT", Value="MT"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="NE", Value="NE"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="NV", Value="NV"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="NH", Value="NH"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="NJ", Value="NJ"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="NM", Value="NM"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="NY", Value="NY"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="NC", Value="NC"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="ND", Value="ND"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="OH", Value="OH"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="OK", Value="OK"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="OR", Value="OR"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="PA", Value="PA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="PR", Value="PR"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="RI", Value="RI"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="SC", Value="SC"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="SD", Value="SD"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="TN", Value="TN"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="TX", Value="TX"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="UT", Value="UT"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="VT", Value="VT"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="VA", Value="VA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="WA", Value="WA"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="WV", Value="WV"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="WI", Value="WI"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="WY", Value="WY"}
        };
        return states;
    }
```

Comment: Another option is to create a list for the dropdown:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/30356044/3175526

Answer (score -1):

In case you wanted a list of countries

public static IEnumerable GetCountryList()
{

```
 IList<SelectListItem> countries = new List<SelectListItem>
 {
     new SelectListItem{Value="AF", Text="Afghanistan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AX", Text="Aland Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AL", Text="Albania"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="DZ", Text="Algeria"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AS", Text="American Samoa"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AD", Text="Andorra"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AO", Text="Angola"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AI", Text="Anguilla"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AQ", Text="Antarctica"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AG", Text="Antigua and Barbuda"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AR", Text="Argentina"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AM", Text="Armenia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AW", Text="Aruba"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AU", Text="Australia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AT", Text="Austria"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AZ", Text="Azerbaijan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BS", Text="Bahamas"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BH", Text="Bahrain"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BD", Text="Bangladesh"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BB", Text="Barbados"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BY", Text="Belarus"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BE", Text="Belgium"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BZ", Text="Belize"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BJ", Text="Benin"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BM", Text="Bermuda"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BT", Text="Bhutan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BO", Text="Bolivia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BQ", Text="Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BA", Text="Bosnia and Herzegovina"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BW", Text="Botswana"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BV", Text="Bouvet Island"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BR", Text="Brazil"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="IO", Text="British Indian Ocean Territory"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BN", Text="Brunei Darussalam"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BG", Text="Bulgaria"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BF", Text="Burkina Faso"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BI", Text="Burundi"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KH", Text="Cambodia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CM", Text="Cameroon"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CA", Text="Canada"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CV", Text="Cape Verde"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KY", Text="Cayman Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CF", Text="Central African Republic"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TD", Text="Chad"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CL", Text="Chile"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CN", Text="China"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CX", Text="Christmas Island"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CC", Text="Cocos(Keeling) Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CO", Text="Colombia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KM", Text="Comoros"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CG", Text="Congo"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CD", Text="Congo, Democratic Republic of the Congo"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CK", Text="Cook Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CR", Text="Costa Rica"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CI", Text="Cote D'Ivoire"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="HR", Text="Croatia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CU", Text="Cuba"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CW", Text="Curacao"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CY", Text="Cyprus"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CZ", Text="Czech Republic"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="DK", Text="Denmark"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="DJ", Text="Djibouti"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="DM", Text="Dominica"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="DO", Text="Dominican Republic"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="EC", Text="Ecuador"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="EG", Text="Egypt"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SV", Text="El Salvador"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GQ", Text="Equatorial Guinea"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="ER", Text="Eritrea"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="EE", Text="Estonia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="ET", Text="Ethiopia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="FK", Text="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="FO", Text="Faroe Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="FJ", Text="Fiji"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="FI", Text="Finland"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="FR", Text="France"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GF", Text="French Guiana"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PF", Text="French Polynesia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TF", Text="French Southern Territories"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GA", Text="Gabon"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GM", Text="Gambia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GE", Text="Georgia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="DE", Text="Germany"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GH", Text="Ghana"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GI", Text="Gibraltar"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GR", Text="Greece"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GL", Text="Greenland"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GD", Text="Grenada"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GP", Text="Guadeloupe"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GU", Text="Guam"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GT", Text="Guatemala"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GG", Text="Guernsey"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GN", Text="Guinea"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GW", Text="Guinea - Bissau"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GY", Text="Guyana"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="HT", Text="Haiti"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="HM", Text="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="VA", Text="Holy See (Vatican City State)"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="HN", Text="Honduras"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="HK", Text="Hong Kong"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="HU", Text="Hungary"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="IS", Text="Iceland"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="IN", Text="India"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="ID", Text="Indonesia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="IR", Text="Iran, Islamic Republic of"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="IQ", Text="Iraq"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="IE", Text="Ireland"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="IM", Text="Isle of Man"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="IL", Text="Israel"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="IT", Text="Italy"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="JM", Text="Jamaica"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="JP", Text="Japan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="JE", Text="Jersey"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="JO", Text="Jordan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KZ", Text="Kazakhstan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KE", Text="Kenya"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KI", Text="Kiribati"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KP", Text="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KR", Text="Korea, Republic of"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="XK", Text="Kosovo"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KW", Text="Kuwait"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KG", Text="Kyrgyzstan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LA", Text="Lao People's Democratic Republic"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LV", Text="Latvia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LB", Text="Lebanon"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LS", Text="Lesotho"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LR", Text="Liberia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LY", Text="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LI", Text="Liechtenstein"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LT", Text="Lithuania"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LU", Text="Luxembourg"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MO", Text="Macao"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MK", Text="Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MG", Text="Madagascar"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MW", Text="Malawi"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MY", Text="Malaysia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MV", Text="Maldives"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="ML", Text="Mali"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MT", Text="Malta"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MH", Text="Marshall Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MQ", Text="Martinique"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MR", Text="Mauritania"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MU", Text="Mauritius"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="YT", Text="Mayotte"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MX", Text="Mexico"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="FM", Text="Micronesia, Federated States of"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MD", Text="Moldova, Republic of"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MC", Text="Monaco"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MN", Text="Mongolia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="ME", Text="Montenegro"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MS", Text="Montserrat"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MA", Text="Morocco"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MZ", Text="Mozambique"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MM", Text="Myanmar"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NA", Text="Namibia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NR", Text="Nauru"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NP", Text="Nepal"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NL", Text="Netherlands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AN", Text="Netherlands Antilles"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NC", Text="New Caledonia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NZ", Text="New Zealand"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NI", Text="Nicaragua"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NE", Text="Niger"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NG", Text="Nigeria"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NU", Text="Niue"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NF", Text="Norfolk Island"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MP", Text="Northern Mariana Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="NO", Text="Norway"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="OM", Text="Oman"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PK", Text="Pakistan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PW", Text="Palau"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PS", Text="Palestinian Territory, Occupied"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PA", Text="Panama"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PG", Text="Papua New Guinea"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PY", Text="Paraguay"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PE", Text="Peru"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PH", Text="Philippines"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PN", Text="Pitcairn"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PL", Text="Poland"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PT", Text="Portugal"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PR", Text="Puerto Rico"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="QA", Text="Qatar"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="RE", Text="Reunion"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="RO", Text="Romania"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="RU", Text="Russian Federation"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="RW", Text="Rwanda"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="BL", Text="Saint Barthelemy"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SH", Text="Saint Helena"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="KN", Text="Saint Kitts and Nevis"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LC", Text="Saint Lucia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="MF", Text="Saint Martin"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="PM", Text="Saint Pierre and Miquelon"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="VC", Text="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="WS", Text="Samoa"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SM", Text="San Marino"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="ST", Text="Sao Tome and Principe"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SA", Text="Saudi Arabia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SN", Text="Senegal"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="RS", Text="Serbia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CS", Text="Serbia and Montenegro"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SC", Text="Seychelles"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SL", Text="Sierra Leone"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SG", Text="Singapore"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SX", Text="Sint Maarten"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SK", Text="Slovakia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SI", Text="Slovenia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SB", Text="Solomon Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SO", Text="Somalia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="ZA", Text="South Africa"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GS", Text="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SS", Text="South Sudan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="ES", Text="Spain"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="LK", Text="Sri Lanka"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SD", Text="Sudan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SR", Text="Suriname"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SJ", Text="Svalbard and Jan Mayen"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SZ", Text="Swaziland"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SE", Text="Sweden"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="CH", Text="Switzerland"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="SY", Text="Syrian Arab Republic"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TW", Text="Taiwan, Province of China"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TJ", Text="Tajikistan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TZ", Text="Tanzania, United Republic of"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TH", Text="Thailand"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TL", Text="Timor - Leste"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TG", Text="Togo"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TK", Text="Tokelau"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TO", Text="Tonga"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TT", Text="Trinidad and Tobago"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TN", Text="Tunisia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TR", Text="Turkey"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TM", Text="Turkmenistan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TC", Text="Turks and Caicos Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="TV", Text="Tuvalu"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="UG", Text="Uganda"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="UA", Text="Ukraine"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="AE", Text="United Arab Emirates"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="GB", Text="United Kingdom"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="US", Text="United States"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="UM", Text="United States Minor Outlying Islands"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="UY", Text="Uruguay"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="UZ", Text="Uzbekistan"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="VU", Text="Vanuatu"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="VE", Text="Venezuela"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="VN", Text="Viet Nam"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="VG", Text="Virgin Islands, British"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="VI", Text="Virgin Islands, U.s."},
     new SelectListItem{Value="WF", Text="Wallis and Futuna"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="EH", Text="Western Sahara"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="YE", Text="Yemen"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="ZM", Text="Zambia"},
     new SelectListItem{Value="ZW", Text="Zimbabwe"}

 };
 return countries;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Best way to make drop down list:

```
grid.Column("PriceType",canSort:true,header: "PriceType",format: @<span>
    <span id="spanPriceType_@item.ShoppingCartID">@item.PriceTypeDescription</span>
    @Html.DropDownList("PriceType"+(int)item.ShoppingCartID,new SelectList(MvcApplication1.Services.ExigoApiContext.CreateODataContext().PriceTypes.Select(s => new { s.PriceTypeID, s.PriceTypeDescription }).AsEnumerable(),"PriceTypeID", "PriceTypeDescription",Convert.ToInt32(item.PriceTypeId)), new { @class = "PriceType",@style="width:120px;display:none",@selectedvalue="selected"})
        </span>),
```

Comment: The readability of this is terrible. Not the best way to make a drop down list.

Comment: This is a Way to create a dropdown list far from best.