# MVC 4. How to create SelectListItem for multiple dropdown box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to create SelectListItem with selected items in Controller and then pass it to view. Question is how from testTypeIDs = "1,3" create **selectedTestTypes**, so it can be used like that:
ViewBag.testTypeID = new SelectList(db.testTypes, "typeID", "typeName", **selectedTestTypes**);

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539149/how-to-create-select-list-for-country-and-states-province-in-mvc/18539308#18539308

Answer (score 0):

Found simple solution with Array!!!!

```
selectedTestTypes = Array.ConvertAll(testTypeIDs.Split(','), int.Parse);
```

and replaced SelectList on MultiSelectList

```
ViewBag.testTypeID = new MultiSelectList(db.testTypes, "typeID", "typeName", selectedTestTypes);
```

Comment: There is no point using the last parameter (`selectedTestTypes`) if your binding to a property. If the property your binding to is `int[] { 1, 3 }` then the options with values 1 and 3 will be selected (`selectedTestTypes` is just ignored)