# Populating a dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC 5 from another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist that will contain department names.  This dropdownlist will be in located in a view that is part of creating a new user.  I have two separate models as follows:

```
public class User : MongoEntity
{
    public User()
    {
        DepartmentName = new List<Department>();
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string LoginName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Department> DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Department : MongoEntity
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentLocation { get; set; }
}
```

I have been unable to pull the values from the Department Model into the CreateUser view.

I am using MongoDB for this project.  Any help/feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are several ways to do it.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539149/how-to-create-select-list-for-country-and-states-province-in-mvc/18539308#18539308 for one way

Comment: Could you post the code that you are using that tries to access the departments?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is not about dropdownlist, but about populating a list from MongoDB. Try to make DepartmentName virtual:

```
public virtual List<Department> DepartmentName { get; set; }
```

Btw, it comes to mind that this property should be named "Departments" instead of "DepartmentName".

PS Show us more code if it won't help.