# Populate drop down in MVC using different View and Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, architecture

I'm creating an internal CMS system. I have a page that retrieves an Item and allows the user to carry our various administrative tasks.

Lets look at the following:

> Quote (Page)
>
> Item (Page) - ItemDetails (Partial within Item) - Artwork (partial within ItemDetails)

A user selects a quote. Then views an Item which retrieves an item with associated content. Within an Item, they can select Artwork or any other tabs (partial views also).

The user then has the ability to change values for an internal CMS system. I want to:

1. Pre-populate several different dropdown lists. (If it helps, I have some pre-formatted select tags, I could re-use, was used in an angular project).
2. These Dropdown boxes should be pre-loaded with any existing values if found attached to an item.
3. Have a form with the ability to change the value and update it.

Having just moved to MVC, I'm struggling to nail it, despite scouring for over a day on various guides/tutorials. Just in case you're wondering why I'm wanting to separate the controllers, it's because the project is going to become vast. Architecturally, it makes sense.

Example: Mockup Types is within Artwork. I've used entity framework and I'm retrieving all my MockupTypes successfully.

The first partial:

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Item.Views.ViewNames._TabbedItemDetailsPanel, Model.SelectedItem)
```

SelectedItem viewModel:

```
public class SelectedItem
{
    public ArtworkDetailViewModel ArtworkDetail { get; set; }
    //Several others
}
```

ArtworkDetail contains:

```
public class ArtworkDetailViewModel : DataViewModel
{
    public int? ItemID { get; set; }
    public FaceColourViewModel FaceColour { get; set; }
    public MockupTypeViewModel MockupType { get; set; }
    public ProofingTypeViewModel ProofType { get; set; }
    //Others
}
```

This is brought in by the item controller:

```
public partial class ItemController : Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult ItemDetail(int itemId)
    {
        var model = new QuotePageViewModel();
        var item = itemViewModelService.GetItemByID(itemId);
        model.LiveQuotes = quotesOverviewViewModelService.GetItemsByQuote(item.QuoteID.Value);
        model.SelectedItem = item;
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Within the partial posted above, I have a tab for Artwork, which is another separate partial view:

```
 @Html.Partial(MVC.Item.Views._TabbedArtwork, new ViewModels.Artwork.ArtworkAttributesViewModel())
```

My thinking is the ArtworkAttributesViewModel will have a list of pre-populated models

```
public class ArtworkAttributesViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ProofingTypeViewModel> ProofTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MockupTypeViewModel> MockupTypes { get; set; }
    //Others
}
```

This comes from a separate controller called Artwork.

```
public partial class ArtworkDetailController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult GetAttributes()
    {
        var model = new ArtworkAttributesViewModel();
        model = artworkAttributesViewModelService.GetArtworkAttributes();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Within _TabbedArtwork, I started to create a form:

```
@model  ViewModels.Artwork.ArtworkAttributesViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.ArtworkDetail.ActionNames.Index, MVC.ArtworkDetail.Name, FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p><strong></strong> <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row show-grid">
            <p class="margin-bottom-zero"><strong>Mockup Types</strong></p>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor()
                    <select class="selectpicker"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

In summary, I have 2 partials, 2 viewmodels and 2 controllers. How on earth do I bring all of this this together?

Much appreciated.

Edit: Still battling on getting the second controller to send the view to the partial

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539149/how-to-create-select-list-for-country-and-states-province-in-mvc/18539308#18539308 .  Change class to the path to that class on the different controllers and it should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the dropdown to the item to be edited and the model to populate it.

```
public class mainitem() {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
}

public class type() {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class myviewmodel() {
    public mainitem item { get; set; }
    public List<type> types { get; set; }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.item.type, 
           new SelectList(Model.types, "id", "name"), "-Select-", 
           new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: How do I get my viewmodel to call the other controller in order to populate my selectlist? Thanks

Comment: You should create a viewmodel with all of the lists you need and bind it to the view in the controller action for that view

Comment: Isn't that bad practice? I'll end up lumping about 70 viewmodels in one class, I was hoping there would be a way to separate them out?

Comment: My understanding was that a viewmodel provides the data for a view. Thus viewmodel. If you have 70 views I would presume you would need 70 viewmodels unless you can re-use them. A viewmodel can be called from any controller and passed to any view.