# what should i put into a SelectList asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

do i have to put all the model's attributes into the SelectList or just those that i need?

```
ViewBag.idProfil = new SelectList(db.Profils, "idProfil", "libelleP");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SelectList` consists of corresponding text (what the user see's) and the corresponding value (a unique identifier to distinguish which list item was chosen). For example, if you wanted the text property to be **libelleP** and the value property to be **idProfil**, you could construct a list like so:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> myDropDownListSource = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem() { libelleP="firstItem", idProfil=1},
    new SelectListItem() { libelleP="secondItem", idProfil=2}
    // Add as many list items here as you like
};
```

Now when your list is fully populated with all of the list items that you want, you can simply call it inside the view like so:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Profils, Class.myDropDownListSource )`

**Note**: It's better practice to put the `SelectList` inside your Model as a property. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539149/how-to-create-select-list-for-country-and-states-province-in-mvc)

*Disclaimer: This code has not been tested and is merely to get you on the right track.*