# No ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I get this error, for a Html.DropDownListFor using a SelectList, yet the key it complains about does exist.

The error:

```
 There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ObjectionRequirement.FkRequirementStatusId'.
```

The Object structure:

```
public class ObjectionRequirementViewModel
{
    public ObjectionRequirement ObjectionRequirement { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectionRequirement> ObjectionRequirements { get; set; } 
    public object RequirementStatusLookup { get; set; }

    public ObjectionRequirementViewModel()
    {
        this.ObjectionRequirement = new ObjectionRequirement();
        this.ObjectionRequirements = new List<ObjectionRequirement>();
        this.RequirementStatusLookup = null;
    }
}

public class ObjectionRequirement
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Requirement { get; set; }
    public int? FkRequirementStatusId { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectionRequirementStatus
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Code setting the ViewModels RequirementStatusLookup

```
List<ObjectionRequirementStatus> requirementStatuses = getRequirementStatuses();

ObjectionRequirementViewModel model = new ObjectionRequirementViewModel();
model.RequirementStatusLookup = new SelectList(requirementStatuses, "Id", "Status", selectedStatusId);
```

The Markup:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ObjectionRequirement.FkRequirementStatusId,
          (SelectList)Model.RequirementStatusLookup)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor) help?

Comment: Nope, Saw that, tried it but does not help me, thx though

Comment: I would have RequirementStatusLookup as public List<SelectListItem> RequirementStatusLookup{get;set;) in your model then fill with each item avoiding the (SlectList) cast. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539149/how-to-create-select-list-for-country-and-states-province-in-mvc)

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track