# List of All Countries DropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I used this code to populate my dropdownlist with countries list:

```
public JsonResult GetAllCountries()
{
    var objDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var cultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
    {
        var regionInfo = new RegionInfo(cultureInfo.Name);
        if (!objDict.ContainsKey(regionInfo.EnglishName))
        {
            objDict.Add(cultureInfo.EnglishName, regionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToLower());
        }
    }
    var obj = objDict.OrderBy(p => p.Key).ToArray();

    return Json(obj.Select(t => new 
    { 
        Text = t.Key, 
        Value = t.Value 
    }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It populates [This Way](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pqtb1T). And I used same code but Console, and shows differently [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aIuUcg). Why? And what should I do to populate the dropdownlist like the second one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line

`objDic.Add(cultureInfo.EnglishName, regionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToLower());`

Should read

`objDic.Add(regionInfo.EnglishName, regionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToLower());`

This will have the website output the same as the console app

Comment: Thanks @3dd, appreciated!