# Where can I find a standardized US States and Canadian Provinces Java Map, abbreviations to full names

Tags: java, dictionary

I need a Java dictionary to look up full state and province names from  North American state and province abbreviations. For example, "TX" --> "Texas", "NS" --> "Nova Scotia".

I found the C# versions here: [Standardized US States Array and Countries Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367529/standardized-us-states-array-and-countries-array/65463635)

What is the Java version using the Map collection?

Comment: Just read any basic tutorial on how to create and populate a `Map` in Java... Seriously, the linked C# code also just creates a static hardcoded list in the code. You can do that as well.

Comment: My need specifically is to avoid having to look up the North American abbreviations and full names, knowing that countless Java programmers have done this before.

Comment: So you are searching for an external library that is maintained by someone else which you can just add to your project dependencies or what? I.e. the answer given by yourself does NOT answer your own question? Neither does the given C# code? You have to be very precise when asking a question.

Comment: Reworded the comment to be more precise.

Comment: Imo nothing really changed due to your edit. I still dont get why the below answer does not solve your issue. It provides such a map, in Java.

Comment: The below answer indeed solves my issue - completely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java dictionary, mapping US state and Canadian province abbreviations to full names, adapted from the C# versions mentioned in the question. It uses static initialization for brevity.

```
// the US State and Canada abbreviation dictionary, abbreviation --> full name
private final static Map<String, String>  stateAbbreviationDictionary = new HashMap<>();

static {
  // USA
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("AL", "Alabama");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("AK", "Alaska");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("AZ", "Arizona");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("AR", "Arkansas");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("CA", "California");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("CO", "Colorado");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("CT", "Connecticut");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("DE", "Delaware");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("DC", "District Of Columbia");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("FL", "Florida");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("GA", "Georgia");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("HI", "Hawaii");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("ID", "Idaho");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("IL", "Illinois");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("IN", "Indiana");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("IA", "Iowa");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("KS", "Kansas");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("KY", "Kentucky");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("LA", "Louisiana");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("ME", "Maine");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("MD", "Maryland");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("MA", "Massachusetts");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("MI", "Michigan");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("MN", "Minnesota");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("MS", "Mississippi");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("MO", "Missouri");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("MT", "Montana");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NE", "Nebraska");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NV", "Nevada");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NH", "New Hampshire");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NJ", "New Jersey");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NM", "New Mexico");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NY", "New York");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NC", "North Carolina");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("ND", "North Dakota");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("OH", "Ohio");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("OK", "Oklahoma");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("OR", "Oregon");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("PA", "Pennsylvania");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("RI", "Rhode Island");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("SC", "South Carolina");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("SD", "South Dakota");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("TN", "Tennessee");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("TX", "Texas");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("UT", "Utah");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("VT", "Vermont");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("VA", "Virginia");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("WA", "Washington");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("WV", "West Virginia");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("WI", "Wisconsin");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("WY", "Wyoming");
  // Canada
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("AB", "Alberta");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("BC", "British Columbia");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("MB", "Manitoba");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NB", "New Brunswick");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NL", "Newfoundland and Labrador");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NS", "Nova Scotia");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NT", "Northwest Territories");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("NU", "Nunavut");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("ON", "Ontario");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("PE", "Prince Edward Island");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("QC", "Quebec");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("SK", "Saskatchewan");
  stateAbbreviationDictionary.put("YT", "Yukon");
}
```

Java 9 introduced immutable maps and here is the same dictionary implemented as an immutable map:

```
// the US State and Canada abbreviation dictionary, abbreviation --> full name
  private final static Map<String, String> stateAbbreviationDictionary = Map.ofEntries(
          // USA
          entry("AL", "Alabama"),
          entry("AK", "Alaska"),
          entry("AZ", "Arizona"),
          entry("AR", "Arkansas"),
          entry("CA", "California"),
          entry("CO", "Colorado"),
          entry("CT", "Connecticut"),
          entry("DE", "Delaware"),
          entry("DC", "District Of Columbia"),
          entry("FL", "Florida"),
          entry("GA", "Georgia"),
          entry("HI", "Hawaii"),
          entry("ID", "Idaho"),
          entry("IL", "Illinois"),
          entry("IN", "Indiana"),
          entry("IA", "Iowa"),
          entry("KS", "Kansas"),
          entry("KY", "Kentucky"),
          entry("LA", "Louisiana"),
          entry("ME", "Maine"),
          entry("MD", "Maryland"),
          entry("MA", "Massachusetts"),
          entry("MI", "Michigan"),
          entry("MN", "Minnesota"),
          entry("MS", "Mississippi"),
          entry("MO", "Missouri"),
          entry("MT", "Montana"),
          entry("NE", "Nebraska"),
          entry("NV", "Nevada"),
          entry("NH", "New Hampshire"),
          entry("NJ", "New Jersey"),
          entry("NM", "New Mexico"),
          entry("NY", "New York"),
          entry("NC", "North Carolina"),
          entry("ND", "North Dakota"),
          entry("OH", "Ohio"),
          entry("OK", "Oklahoma"),
          entry("OR", "Oregon"),
          entry("PA", "Pennsylvania"),
          entry("RI", "Rhode Island"),
          entry("SC", "South Carolina"),
          entry("SD", "South Dakota"),
          entry("TN", "Tennessee"),
          entry("TX", "Texas"),
          entry("UT", "Utah"),
          entry("VT", "Vermont"),
          entry("VA", "Virginia"),
          entry("WA", "Washington"),
          entry("WV", "West Virginia"),
          entry("WI", "Wisconsin"),
          entry("WY", "Wyoming"),
          // Canada
          entry("AB", "Alberta"),
          entry("BC", "British Columbia"),
          entry("MB", "Manitoba"),
          entry("NB", "New Brunswick"),
          entry("NL", "Newfoundland and Labrador"),
          entry("NS", "Nova Scotia"),
          entry("NT", "Northwest Territories"),
          entry("NU", "Nunavut"),
          entry("ON", "Ontario"),
          entry("PE", "Prince Edward Island"),
          entry("QC", "Quebec"),
          entry("SK", "Saskatchewan"),
          entry("YT", "Yukon"));
```